# How to display traffic aware polylines in flutter app

Tags: flutter, google-maps, polyline

So first I saw Google preferred route api, I read the docs and it has an endpoint that returns traffic conditions along a route and legs, the I proceeded to try it out in postman  but the response does not contain the most important part "speedReadingIntervals",

My request was a copy and paste of the example in the docs

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes_preferred/traffic_on_polylines

So does anyone know how what I might be doing wrong?.

Is there an alternative way to show traffic on a polyline in flutter?

This is the endpoint url "https://routes.googleapis.com/directions/v2:computeRoutes"

This is the request body, request header and response

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Two things. First, do you have the "TRAFFIC_AWARE" or "TRAFFIC_AWARE_OPTIMAL" preferences enabled per the [RouteTravelAdvisory](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes_preferred/reference/rest/Shared.Types/RouteTravelAdvisory) object documentation? Second, not all roads will have traffic info for them, particularly minor and residential roads, so make sure you're testing on something like a major highway during rush hour.

Comment: I added "TRAFFIC_AWARE" to body of my request, please check my edited question to see what I did in full.